# Can we convert Javascript hash implementations to a defined set of characters?

Tags: javascript, hash

I'm currently looking at these [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6122571/simple-non-secure-hash-function-for-javascript?noredirect=1&lq=1) and these [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7616461/8861646).

However, what I need is some hashing function that returns 10-25 characters from a definite set of characters: `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz -'` (instead of hex characters or an integer)

I'm not trying to do crypto, I'm just trying to always get the same output for the same input.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding possibly base64 may be your friend? or an MD5 implementation.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655769/fastest-md5-implementation-in-javascript yeah MD5 is crypto, but maybe simplier :)

Comment: @MatthiasBurger Then how do you convert the result to a 10-25 characters long string from a definite set of characters?