# Scrambling and descrambling javascript array with salt

Tags: javascript, algorithm, permutation, scramble

So i made a javascript string scrambler with md5.

```js
var MD5 = function(d){var r = M(V(Y(X(d),8*d.length)));return r.toLowerCase()};function M(d){for(var _,m="0123456789ABCDEF",f="",r=0;r<d.length;r++)_=d.charCodeAt(r),f+=m.charAt(_>>>4&15)+m.charAt(15&_);return f}function X(d){for(var _=Array(d.length>>2),m=0;m<_.length;m++)_[m]=0;for(m=0;m<8*d.length;m+=8)_[m>>5]|=(255&d.charCodeAt(m/8))<<m%32;return _}function V(d){for(var _="",m=0;m<32*d.length;m+=8)_+=String.fromCharCode(d[m>>5]>>>m%32&255);return _}function Y(d,_){d[_>>5]|=128<<_%32,d[14+(_+64>>>9<<4)]=_;for(var m=1732584193,f=-271733879,r=-1732584194,i=271733878,n=0;n<d.length;n+=16){var h=m,t=f,g=r,e=i;f=md5_ii(f=md5_ii(f=md5_ii(f=md5_ii(f=md5_hh(f=md5_hh(f=md5_hh(f=md5_hh(f=md5_gg(f=md5_gg(f=md5_gg(f=md5_gg(f=md5_ff(f=md5_ff(f=md5_ff(f=md5_ff(f,r=md5_ff(r,i=md5_ff(i,m=md5_ff(m,f,r,i,d[n+0],7,-680876936),f,r,d[n+1],12,-389564586),m,f,d[n+2],17,606105819),i,m,d[n+3],22,-1044525330),r=md5_ff(r,i=md5_ff(i,m=md5_ff(m,f,r,i,d[n+4],7,-176418897),f,r,d[n+5],12,1200080426),m,f,d[n+6],17,-1473231341),i,m,d[n+7],22,-45705983),r=md5_ff(r,i=md5_ff(i,m=md5_ff(m,f,r,i,d[n+8],7,1770035416),f,r,d[n+9],12,-1958414417),m,f,d[n+10],17,-42063),i,m,d[n+11],22,-1990404162),r=md5_ff(r,i=md5_ff(i,m=md5_ff(m,f,r,i,d[n+12],7,1804603682),f,r,d[n+13],12,-40341101),m,f,d[n+14],17,-1502002290),i,m,d[n+15],22,1236535329),r=md5_gg(r,i=md5_gg(i,m=md5_gg(m,f,r,i,d[n+1],5,-165796510),f,r,d[n+6],9,-1069501632),m,f,d[n+11],14,643717713),i,m,d[n+0],20,-373897302),r=md5_gg(r,i=md5_gg(i,m=md5_gg(m,f,r,i,d[n+5],5,-701558691),f,r,d[n+10],9,38016083),m,f,d[n+15],14,-660478335),i,m,d[n+4],20,-405537848),r=md5_gg(r,i=md5_gg(i,m=md5_gg(m,f,r,i,d[n+9],5,568446438),f,r,d[n+14],9,-1019803690),m,f,d[n+3],14,-187363961),i,m,d[n+8],20,1163531501),r=md5_gg(r,i=md5_gg(i,m=md5_gg(m,f,r,i,d[n+13],5,-1444681467),f,r,d[n+2],9,-51403784),m,f,d[n+7],14,1735328473),i,m,d[n+12],20,-1926607734),r=md5_hh(r,i=md5_hh(i,m=md5_hh(m,f,r,i,d[n+5],4,-378558),f,r,d[n+8],11,-2022574463),m,f,d[n+11],16,1839030562),i,m,d[n+14],23,-35309556),r=md5_hh(r,i=md5_hh(i,m=md5_hh(m,f,r,i,d[n+1],4,-1530992060),f,r,d[n+4],11,1272893353),m,f,d[n+7],16,-155497632),i,m,d[n+10],23,-1094730640),r=md5_hh(r,i=md5_hh(i,m=md5_hh(m,f,r,i,d[n+13],4,681279174),f,r,d[n+0],11,-358537222),m,f,d[n+3],16,-722521979),i,m,d[n+6],23,76029189),r=md5_hh(r,i=md5_hh(i,m=md5_hh(m,f,r,i,d[n+9],4,-640364487),f,r,d[n+12],11,-421815835),m,f,d[n+15],16,530742520),i,m,d[n+2],23,-995338651),r=md5_ii(r,i=md5_ii(i,m=md5_ii(m,f,r,i,d[n+0],6,-198630844),f,r,d[n+7],10,1126891415),m,f,d[n+14],15,-1416354905),i,m,d[n+5],21,-57434055),r=md5_ii(r,i=md5_ii(i,m=md5_ii(m,f,r,i,d[n+12],6,1700485571),f,r,d[n+3],10,-1894986606),m,f,d[n+10],15,-1051523),i,m,d[n+1],21,-2054922799),r=md5_ii(r,i=md5_ii(i,m=md5_ii(m,f,r,i,d[n+8],6,1873313359),f,r,d[n+15],10,-30611744),m,f,d[n+6],15,-1560198380),i,m,d[n+13],21,1309151649),r=md5_ii(r,i=md5_ii(i,m=md5_ii(m,f,r,i,d[n+4],6,-145523070),f,r,d[n+11],10,-1120210379),m,f,d[n+2],15,718787259),i,m,d[n+9],21,-343485551),m=safe_add(m,h),f=safe_add(f,t),r=safe_add(r,g),i=safe_add(i,e)}return Array(m,f,r,i)}function md5_cmn(d,_,m,f,r,i){return safe_add(bit_rol(safe_add(safe_add(_,d),safe_add(f,i)),r),m)}function md5_ff(d,_,m,f,r,i,n){return md5_cmn(_&m|~_&f,d,_,r,i,n)}function md5_gg(d,_,m,f,r,i,n){return md5_cmn(_&f|m&~f,d,_,r,i,n)}function md5_hh(d,_,m,f,r,i,n){return md5_cmn(_^m^f,d,_,r,i,n)}function md5_ii(d,_,m,f,r,i,n){return md5_cmn(m^(_|~f),d,_,r,i,n)}function safe_add(d,_){var m=(65535&d)+(65535&_);return(d>>16)+(_>>16)+(m>>16)<<16|65535&m}function bit_rol(d,_){return d<<_|d>>>32-_}

var hex = {
    a: 10,
    b: 11,
    c: 13,
    d: 14,
    e: 15,
    f: 16
}

function scrambleText(text, salt) {
    if(text.length > 32) throw "No more than 32 chars.";

    var strs = text.split("");
    var final = "";

    var hash = MD5(salt);
    var hashlength = hash.length, i = 0;

    while(i < hashlength) {
        if(!strs.length) break;
        var num = (hex[hash[i]] || parseInt(hash[i])) * 2 % strs.length;
        final += strs[num];
        strs.splice(num, 1);
        ++i;
    }
    return final
}
```

I can scramble strings but how do I unscramble the scrambled text assuming I know the salt?

I tried an attempt but it's not doing a good job

```js
function unscrambleText(text, salt) {
    var strs = text.split("");

    var hash = MD5(salt);
    var hashlength = hash.length, i = strs.length - 1, c = 0;;

    var final = [];

    while(i >= 0) {
        var num = (hex[hash[i]] || parseInt(hash[i])) * 2 % (strs.length - i);
        final[num] = strs[c];

        final += strs[num];
        strs.splice(num, 1);
        --i;
        ++c;
    }
    return final
}
```

Can you guys help me solve this problem? I have been trying for hours.

I take the md5 of the string called "salt" then use it as a reference to scramble the string. I only use strings to simplify the problem. In my actual code, I have an array of image datas that I want to scramble, then be able to descramble it
[example of image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQkyu.png)

Comment: http://www.aspencrypt.com/crypto101_hash.html

Comment: This isnt secure for obvious reasons. And if you plan on using https/ssl, then why scramble?

Comment: @Will I am not decrypting the md5 hash but using it as a reference to scramble the string.

Comment: @GetSet I am not using this code to secure something. It's just an algorithm to scramble strings. I take the md5 of the string called "salt" then use it as a reference to scramble the string.

Comment: But why? ... Why are you scrambling on such?

Comment: @GetSet I only use strings to simplify the problem. In my actual code, I have an array of image datas that I want to scramble, then be able to descramble it

Comment: I just use an array of chars as a place holder.

Comment: Why scramble at all is my question?

Comment: @GetSet for image encryption purposes

Comment: Please don't use `md5` or the term "salt", they have nothing to do with what you're doing here. The variable named `hash` is a *key*, and your encryption is a [permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) (like a shuffle). There is nothing secure about it.

Comment: I'm sorry for misusing terms, I'm kind of new in md5. I'll remove the tags.

Comment: Where in your `unscrambleText` are `final` and `chunks` initialised?

Comment: @Bergi sorry, I updated it. But I think the unscramble function i made is a total failure

Comment: Why scramble at all becomes the question. Its not secure. Why? Because the scrambler is in the source. If just want to fool the layman, then you dont need to scramble. Just transpose.

Comment: `for image encryption purposes` ... but when you display the image, it's unencrypted right? Waste of computing power.

Comment: @GetSet I kind of mistermed that too I guess. When I said encryption purposes, I meant scrambling the block of pixels of the image so it will not be viewable to the human eye. https://imgur.com/a/s8ImjOh

Answer (score 1):

Here's a silly script to scramble/unscramble text.

The hash function is from here: [Simple (non-secure) hash function for JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6122571/simple-non-secure-hash-function-for-javascript) Apparently, it's a JavaScript version of a Java hash function.

The script takes the "salt", hashes it, and uses each character in the hash as an offset to shift the letters up or down the ascii table. So it's essentially [ROT *n*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13) where *n* is one of the values of the hashed salt. "Rotten" is probably a pretty good description of this scramble function :D.

```js
const hash = (str) =>
  str.split("").reduce((hash, char) => {
    hash = (hash << 5) - hash + char.charCodeAt(0);
    return hash & hash;
  }, 0);

const offset = (num, i) =>
  parseInt(num.toString().charAt(i % num.toString().length));

const scramble = (st, sa, d = 1) =>
  st
    .split("")
    .map((c, i) => String.fromCharCode(c.charCodeAt(0) + offset(sa, i) * d))
    .join("");

const unscramble = (str, salt) => scramble(str, salt, -1);

const salt = "This is my salt";
const str = "My text to 'scramble'.";

const scram = scramble(str, hash(salt));
const unscram = unscramble(scram, hash(salt));

console.log("scrambled:", scram);
console.log("unscrambled:", unscram);
```

Comment: Hi, can you check out the image i included in the question? Check out also the comments on my questions if you haven't yet. I misused terms and I updated the tags.